# Formatting Excel (xlsx) columns to number with XSL Stylesheet

Tags: excel, xslt, extjs

i have got a Ext.Net Web Application with an Excel (xlsx)export functionality, and would like to format some colums eg. A1 C1 H1 as a number, because all columns are represanted as strings.

```
here is my xsl-template:
 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Worksheet>
      <xsl:attribute name="ss:Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name(/*/*)" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
        <Row>
          <xsl:for-each select="*[position() = 1]/*">
            <Cell>
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
              </Data>
            </Cell>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Row>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </Table>
    </Worksheet>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please share your xml input.

Answer (score 1):

The way to work out how to format your values as numbers in Excel, is to ask Excel itself! Or rather, open up a blank worksheet in Excel, enter a value in a field and format is as a number, and then save the worksheet in Xml Spreadsheet 2003 format. Then open the file in Notepad, or similar, to see what has actually been done.

In this case you may see Excel has added a **Style** element, possibly like this

```
<Style ss:ID="s62">
    <NumberFormat ss:Format="Fixed"/>
</Style>
```

Or maybe like this (there will be lots of ways to format the number)

```
<Style ss:ID="s63">
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0.00"/>
</Style>
```

Then, it is just a case of referencing the style on your table cell, as well as setting the correct type for the data. Like so

```
<Row>
   <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">123</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
   <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="Number">1233</Data></Cell>
</Row>
```

Just bear in mind that the **Style** elements have to be placed in a parent **Styles** that comes before the **Worksheet** element you have above. Something like this, perhaps...

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
<Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62">
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="Fixed"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s63">
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0.00"/>
  </Style>
</Styles>
<Worksheet>
  <xsl:attribute name="ss:Name">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name(/*/*)" />
  </xsl:attribute>
  <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
    <Row>
      <xsl:for-each select="*[position() = 1]/*">
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
          </Data>
        </Cell>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Row>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Table>
</Worksheet>
</xsl:template>
```